# Need to extract fields from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, operation

I have extract the 3 usable field from a string. There is no common delimiter, there can be both blank spaces and tabs.

First, what I am doing is replacing all double blanks and tabs by '**'

Given String :

cont =     Gallipelle         04/04/2012 16.03.03         5678

I am using:

cont.Replace(" ", "**").Replace(" ", "**").Replace("  ", "**").Replace("**", "").Trim()

The answer becomes:

****** Gallipelle******04/04/2012 16.03.03************************ 5678*****

Is the approach correct? How do I extract the stuffs from here? I just need all the extracts in string datatype.

Comment: Is it always going to be Name / Date / Number?

Comment: is there a tag that WON'T apear in the source string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex groups to find out three values name, date, number.

A group is defined as (?<group_name><regex_expr>)

So you could write

```
            Regex regex = new Regex("(?<name>(\\S*))(\\s*)(?<date>((\\S*)\\s(\\S*)))(\\s*)(?<number>(\\d*))");
            Match match = regex.Match(yourString);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
                string date = match.Groups["date"].Value;
                string number = match.Groups["number"].Value;
            }
```

\s* matches sequence of whitespaces which includes tabs.
\S* matches sequence of non-whitespace characters.
\d* matches sequence of digits.

Comment: I have to process data with string ............................................................................................................. Nat Att BTEn Week 04/04/2012 16.03.03 5678

Comment: 'Nat Att BTEn Week' is being split into three. Actually this is the first string only.

Comment: You can replace the first group 'name' by (?<name>([^\\d]*))

Comment: fixed, thanks for the help :)

        Regex regex = new Regex("(?<date>(\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}[/]\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}[.]\\d{2}[.]\\d{2}))(\\s*)(?<number>(\\d*))");
        Match match = regex.Match(testText);             
        if (match.Success)             
        {                 
         //nameAlm = match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim();                 
         dataAlm = match.Groups["date"].Value.Trim();                 
         numberAlm = match.Groups["number"].Value.Trim();             
        }
        nameAlm = testText.Replace(dataAlm,"").Replace(numberAlm,"").Trim();

Comment: @Lordlebu Thanks for accepting the answer.. :)
BTW Did you find any workaround to match the name containing a number?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
var fields = cont.Split(new[] { " ", "\t" },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Adding `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` makes sure that if there are multiple consecutive tabs and/or spaces they will "count as one" when extracting the results.

An alternate option would be to use a regular expression.

Comment: Now, the issue is if the first column has a blank space it is being split into two...

Comment: @user1351029: The data format is too weak to let you solve this issue. There's no solution really. Either the data format has to improve, or you will be saddled with bad and brittle code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Regex("\\s+")).Split(yourstring)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Comment: you forget the tab; make it @"[\s\t]+" and it would be correct.

Comment: @NKCSS `\s` matches any white-space characters, including the tab character. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myText="cont = Gallipelle 04/04/2012 16.03.03 5678";
var splitString=myText.split(" ");

// splitString[1] == Gallipelle 
// splitString[2] ==  04/04/2012
// splitString[3] == 16.03.03 
// splitString[4] == 5678
```

Comment: you dont take the multi-space/tab into account.

Answer (score 0):

No. No need to replace it with any other delimiter. You can use String's split function and give 'space' as delimiter character. e.g. in VB.Net:

Dim value As String() = cont.split(CChar(" "))

this will give you a string array whose values you can access: value(0), value(1) and value(2)